# How to set Cron Job for 11 PM to 11:59 PM

Tags: cron

I want to send emails automatically between 9 PM to 9 AM after every  2 minutes.
I have set the cron job as below

```
    */2  21-23, 0-9  *   *   *
```

Its running perfectly But I am not able to set it to include the time between 11 PM-11:59 PM.

Comment: `*/2` - every 2 minutes, `21-23` - between 21 and 23 hours, `0-9` - from 0th to 9th day of the month. Not sure what a comma there is supposed to mean though.

Comment: [crontab.guru for */2 21-23 * * *](http://crontab.guru/#*/2_21-23_*_*_*) explains it well. This will run up to 23.58. Also, as stated by @zerkms , the comma is wrong here.

Comment: The above cron job is working fine. 21-23, 0-9 means its running from 21 to 23 and 0 to 9. but not running between 23-0.